# is it possible to make a virtual box inside a USB

Tags: virtualbox

I have formatted my USB to a fat32, I've seen multiple tutorials on how to make virtualbox.exe run inside of USB using windows programs

But is it possible to run virtualbox from a USB in Ubuntu, and if so how.
Because the portable.exe version I found only runs with windows 
I wasn't sure if it was possible to do with wine and I could find anything on it in the forums

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done it, both with a ***persistent live*** system and with an ***installed*** system (like installed into an internal drive, but into a USB pendrive). I did not use wine, but installed VirtualBox from the repositories, like any other Ubuntu program. It is in the multiverse repository, as can be seen with ***Synaptic*** or the following command

```
$ apt-cache policy virtualbox
virtualbox:
  Installed: 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1
  Candidate: 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.0.18-dfsg-2build1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
```

So Install it (into Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) with

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Check that you get also the **guest additions** (also available from the multiverse repository).

-o-

Download and add the ***Extension pack*** from the VirtualBox web-site

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

It provides support for USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 devices, VirtualBox RDP, disk encryption, NVMe and PXE boot for Intel cards.